# MediaRecorder crashing in android studio 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, mobile

currently developing an app, and within the app i want the abillity to record and save audio. Using MediaRecorder, i developed some functions that can start recording, stop recording, and playback what you have just recorded. Below is the code.

```
    public void startRecording (View view) throws IOException
{
    recordingNow = true;
    stopRecord.setEnabled(true);
    playbackButton.setEnabled(false);
    startRecord.setEnabled(false);

    try {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaRecorder.start();
}
```

debugging shows that it crashes on the last line, when the media recorder is started. Following through the debug, leads us into the android OS files and then the app gets stuck in a loop of crashing with the error message from android studio being "source code does not match the bytecode". Having researched this and attempting the solutions found on SO, none of them seemed to work. Any ideas of why starting the media recorder is crashing my app?